# Push notifications suddenly stopped being delivered in production

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I added push notifications to one of my apps using Parse about a month ago, and it went through the review process fine and was pushed as an update through the App Store. Since then, everything has been going fine I've been using the REST API to send the notifications to all users.

Yesterday, I added push notifications to one of my other apps, following more or less the same process, and was able to get them up and running (while I have not yet submitted the update to the App Store, I have set up the production push provisioning profile).

Today, push notifications for the former app in production stopped working; the pushes successfully send through Parse, and they are delivered to my test device, but they are delivered to my test device *only*. That is, no production apps are receiving push notifications.

I suspect it is something to do with provisioning profiles, but I don't know how to fix it. I've looked around and everything I could find was related to production vs. development provisioning profiles for the app having the issue, which is not the case here since it was already working in production up until this point.

I have no idea how to go about finding the source of this issue (let alone solving it); any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you can probably make use of the Parse platform to check whether the certificate you exported is valid or not. If that's valid, that means that you don't have problem on the exportation.

Then, go check the the App ID you create in the Apple Developer Program whether it's enabled the production version and match the identifier you set in Xcode. In the same time, check whether the provisioning profile is from that App Id. If so, go ahead and open Xcode.

When you deploy to your test device, remember to change to the release mode instead of development mode. Also, better to change the code signing manually.

If the problem is still existing, I think you can probably delete all of your provisioning profiles in Xcode and do the process again.

Comment: Although I've been trying various solutions (including deleting all of the provisioning profiles) for days, none of them seemed to work. However, in my last-ditch attempt to fix it by deleting all of the profiles again, it started working again (without the need to push an update). I may have accidentally used the same signing key somewhere for both apps when generating the profiles, or it may be something entirely different, but regardless, it works now.

Comment: One more case is you might get the certificate conflict. But it's good that it works now. Good luck bro.